# Out of gas problem on contract call

Tags: gas, etherscan, gas-limit, airdrop

Here ether scan links to failed transactions :

- last failed attempt : [etherscan link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe0cc060603d9ae3f64aaeda3cee9458b729160e451e962ebd37809dae13f71fb)
- others : [etherscan link](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa205d797243126f312ae63bb0a5ea9a32fb14f41)
- traced view of contract calls [etherscan link](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x4a76cf3c14da8589217ab5a79c90a0540ae486714b5b7fe4fcced94753a30f0a&type=parity#decoded) (you may just change the tx hash on the URL to view other failed tx's in detail)

The contract call falls into gas error. It is basically chains of contracts making calls to one and another. As we have dig into the problem, we've seen that it fails on the method below.

`Launchpad.sol` [go to contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa205d797243126f312ae63bb0a5ea9a32fb14f41#code)

```js
    /**
    * @dev Function to setup liquidity and transfer all amounts according to defined percents, if softcap not reached set Refunded flag.
    */
    function setupLiquidity() public onlyOwner {
        require(_isSoldOut == true || block.timestamp > _end , "LaunchpadToken: not sold out or time not elapsed yet" );
        require(_isRefunded == false, "Launchpad: refunded is activated");
        require(_isLiquiditySetup == false, "Setup has already been completed");
        _isLiquiditySetup = true;
        if(_raisedETH < _softCap){
            _isRefunded = true;
            return;
        }
        uint256 ethBalance = address(this).balance;
        require(ethBalance > 0, "LaunchpadToken: eth balance needs to be above zero" );
        uint256 liquidityAmount = ethBalance.mul(_liquidityPercent).div(_totalPercent);
        uint256 tokensAmount = _token.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(tokensAmount >= liquidityAmount.mul(_BASE_PRICE).div(_priceUniInv), "Launchpad: Not sufficient tokens amount");
        uint256 teamAmount = ethBalance.mul(_teamPercent).div(_totalPercent);
        uint256 layerFeeAmount = ethBalance.mul(_fee3).div(_totalPercent);
        uint256 supportFeeAmount = ethBalance.mul(_fee1).div(_totalPercent);
        uint256 stakeFeeAmount = ethBalance.mul(_fee1).div(_totalPercent);
        payable(_layerFeeAddress).transfer(layerFeeAmount);
        payable(_supportFeeAddress).transfer(supportFeeAmount);
        payable(_stakeFeeAddress).transfer(stakeFeeAmount);
        payable(_teamWallet).transfer(teamAmount);
        payable(_liquidityCreator).transfer(liquidityAmount);
        _token.safeTransfer(address(_liquidityCreator), liquidityAmount.mul(_BASE_PRICE).div(_priceUniInv));
    }
```

Somehow, it works on testnet; but fails on mainnet.

- Testnet contract : [link](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xf770eb63d4cf9c041971f89b475cb1bf5a873b12)
- Testnet success transaction with `setupLiquidity()` call. [link](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x8942de314a9c8bc5b0a8e415c719eabdb9218a6720137614b7809f6af4694138)

Theories are;

- Chained contract calls have a higher gas limit requirement, [the highest attempt so far](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4a76cf3c14da8589217ab5a79c90a0540ae486714b5b7fe4fcced94753a30f0a) is with 666,666 gas limit but it still fails. Maybe a number of investors caused this, as on testnet very few of them exist. If this is the case, how can we estimate the required gas limit?
- Contract triggered transactions use 2300 gas, no matter how much gas limit initiator transaction has. That looks weird too.

Contracts :

- [Launchpad 1](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa205d797243126f312ae63bb0a5ea9a32fb14f41#code)
- [LayerX](https://etherscan.io/address/0xfb5b0474b28f18a635579c1bf073fc05be1bb63b#readContract)
- [BETFI](https://etherscan.io/address/0xded7f8710da7ed473953c8709eba2f00ddfdbd9b#code)
- [ProxyChiCaller](https://etherscan.io/address/0x85c1a16327bd78836eb7924952b5166315b44c17#code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Launchpad transfers ethers to Layerx using .transfer, so the receiver has 2300 gas stipend

```
payable(_stakeFeeAddress).transfer(stakeFeeAmount);
```

Since Layerx fallback modifies storage it requires more than the 2300 and it cause out of gas error making setupLiquidity revert

```
function() external payable {
    ethToNextStake = ethToNextStake.add(msg.value); 
}
```

Comment: So, the transfer method always uses 2300 gas limit? How do you think it can be updated/fixed? If this is the case, no matter how much we increase the gas limit on our initiator tx, it will always use 2300 on contract call... Should we re-create the contract or what? Also why it did not create problem on testnet, shouldn't it create problem there also?

Comment: @Kerematam The 2300 gas stipend applies when invoking the contract's fallback. Calling a payable function doesn't have such restriction, it will receive all gas available. In the linked ropsten transaction it worked because all calls were to EOA accounts (not contracts).

Comment: Yeah, I see now. Thanks a lot. It seems like their money is locked into the contract. I don't see any way out. Because they hardcoded the addresses.